# I am using the Visual Designer in iOS for a View Controller splash screen but the image does not appear in the center

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

Here is what the designer shows:

[image]

As it might not be clear I will add the XML below:

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16086"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="center" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" misplaced="YES" axis="vertical" distribution="equalCentering" alignment="center" spacing="20" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Zbh-CC-wDS">
                                <rect key="frame" x="107" y="294" width="128" height="136"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="splash_image.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="znN-uk-H0B">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="128" height="80"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="80" id="A2X-j1-ymP"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </imageView>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="ABC" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="EcF-nC-k2o" colorLabel="IBBuiltInLabel-Gray">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="34.5" y="100" width="59" height="36"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="30"/>
                                        <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.20000000000000001" green="0.20000000000000001" blue="0.20000000000000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="Zbh-CC-wDS" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="centerX" id="eih-d4-foy"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Zbh-CC-wDS" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="centerY" constant="-60" id="fGG-ZZ-u69"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="wza-7a-P1J"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1347.826" y="610.71429999999998"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="splash_image.png" width="128" height="128"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Is the centering being done the correct way? Perhaps by looking at the XML it's possible to see a problem.

It's showing that it is not on center but I am not sure why.

I am very new to iOS and this is the first time I have tried anything so I am not very clear on how to edit the layout that was created by someone else.

Comment: set frames first .. then check ....

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain what you mean by "set frames first".  Looking at the XML, can you see anything that might not be done correctly?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way is to press Update frames button

[image]

**OR**

First tap the yellow icon against your view controller shown in image below

[image]

it will take you to the next screen .. press warning sign there will take you to this popUp

[image]

Select update frame ... and press fix misplacement

Comment: This is a way. Also you can use shortcut keys. Added in my answer :)

Comment: there is also update frames button on the bottom ... that resolve the issue as well .. updated my answer .. its more simpler ...

Answer (score 4):

Select the `Stack View`. And press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>alt/option</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to update to the correct position.